# MS Access - Formatting Labels

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, formatting, vba

I am using a form in MS Access 2010 to enter data into a table. I have got the basic functions set up and added some VB code to format it as desired. One of the things I am trying to do is to update the label of a tickbox value when that tickbox is selected - using the code below it works however when I click 'add record' the formatting on the label remains instead of clearing like the data items - I can't work out how to amend this to make it work, I am sure I will have to add a loop or amend the add record button but I have no idea where to start (there are 30+ labels and tickboxes so if there is a quick way without having to reference all the labels that would be preferred). My second issue is because I have used 'AfterUpdate', when I use the form to look through the records already added the formatting doesn't change with the values as no tickbox has been clicked.

```
Private Sub TextBox1Name_AfterUpdate()

   Const LightYellow = 10092543
   If TextBox1Name = -1 Then
       Me.Label1Name.BackStyle = 1
       Me.Label1Name.BackColor = LightYellow
   Else
       Me.Label1Name.BackStyle = 0
   End If
End Sub
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated with this.

Comment: Are you using a continuous form? You can do a lot with checking the control type. Consider, you already have a true and false, so you may not need if and else.

Comment: Your second question is easy - just add a 'Form_Current' event to set/reset the label as needed. As for 'resetting 30+ labels...' after clicking the 'Add' button, you can either loop thru all the Me.Controls looking for checkbox type and reset, or manually have 20+ lines of code to reset (Boo!) This is a good place to recognize the value of having meaningful control names (i.e. chkLarge, chkSmall, etc.) as you can use code to look for names as well as control types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the formatting of the `TextBox1Name` on 3 separate occasions. When a record is updated (as you have), when the record on the form is changed (that is the `OnCurrent` event) or when you add a new record (that is the `OnClick` event on your new record button.

the way I would do it is create a private sub with code very similar to what you have above and then call if from all 3 events. The only change really necessary is:

```
If Nz(TextBox1Name,0) = -1 Then
```

if your `TextBox1Name` has a default value of Null and not something else.

That of course applies to a non-continuous form. For a continuous form things are a little trickier. In that case your best bet is conditional formatting. In fact, you can probably use conditional formatting even for a single form, instead of using VBA.